# Why is the up button present without setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

According to [Google's document](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html), `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` is needed to show the up button.  I created a bare-bone activity using the wizard in Eclipse and specified its parent activity.  I could not find any `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` in the automatically generated code, but the up button is present when this activity is started and it works as expected.  Could anyone shed some light on this?

```
public class FooActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_foo);

            //more code...    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            //more code...  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //more code...  
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you specify a `parentActivityName` in your `AndroidManifest`, `Acitivty` [will check for that and automatically enable the "up" affordance if it's present.](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/688b5105d665a56e6f2f040f3ca89ca3006801df/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L890)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt answer.  Does this mean the document is wrong (i.e. getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) is redundant), or there are circumstances where such call is needed in order to show the up button?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "wrong", but it could probably be reworded to be a little more clear. It does state "Doing so allows the system to facilitate navigation patterns such as Up..." about adding a `parentActivityName`. But in your case it's redundant to call `ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`.

Comment: Is there a circumstance where setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled is needed?  I am asking this because I want to make sure that adding a parentActivityName is all I need to do to have the up button for thousands of different models of Android devices.  I have read the document several times, and it gives me the impression that adding a parentActivityName is "the first step"(quoted from the document), and the second step is calling setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled.  It seems there is even a 3rd step. I am sorry for my limited understanding of the document.

Comment: @Hong No, that's understandable. Saying that adding `parentActivityName` is the "first step", is a little misleading. But as long as you have that attribute, it'll automatically take care of the "up" affordance for you. [Here's a link to the AppCompat source, where the same check is performed for `ActionBarActivity` too](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivityDelegate.java#L119)

Comment: Thank you for the further explanation.  I will ignore setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled unless I find the up button does not work under a circumstance. The reason I am a bit careful about these things is that I have learned in a hard way that some code works for certain Android devices does not work for others. I do not test on every Android version of every form for each app update, so I have this constant fair.

Answer (score 3):

I described all possible combinations below and their outcomes:

1. You have both `android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity`and this `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` - back button appears and it works;
2. You only have this `android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity` - back button appears and it works, the same as above;
3. You only have this `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`, - back button appears but clicking on it doesn't go anywhere;
4. You have set the parameter to false in this `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);`, even though you have this `android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity` in the manifest, the back button doesn't show up.

That's how this works my friend.