# Home Button on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am new to android development and was following the "[Adding Action Bar Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html)"

I was trying to get the home (back carrot) button on the action bar to enable my app to go back to the main activity.

It is mentioned in the tutorial that this can be done without handling the up button event, if the parent is defined in the xml.

below is my xml file

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.firstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

but pressing the carrot button does not work. what can i be doing wrong?

EDIT:
adding the activity code below

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*
         * setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message); if
         * (savedInstanceState == null) {
         * getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() .add(R.id.container,
         * new PlaceholderFragment()).commit(); }
         */

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        /*
         * switch (item.getItemId()) { case android.R.id.home: Intent intent =
         * new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
         * com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.class);
         * intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         * startActivity(intent); return true; default: return
         * super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); }
         */
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity is below

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                // openSearch();
                EditText temp1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
                temp1.setText("Search");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // openSettings();
                EditText temp2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
                temp2.setText("Settings");
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: are you getting the button click. do you code for some log or toast to know that

Comment: post your activity code.

Comment: I have added the activity code in the edit

Comment: i have to change the min sdk version to 11 for this. I was using 8. I changed it to 11 and it is still not working. In my app the MainActivity is calling the DisplayMessageActivity. and I using this setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled() in DisplayMessageActivity. I have added the MainActivity code as well. This is really frustrating

Comment: @Newton [It's actually redundant to call `ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`, if you're using the `parentActivityName` attribute.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22812771/420015). That being said, when you remove that line from your `DisplayMessageActivity`, is the "up" affordance still present?

Comment: yes the button appears but it does not navigate back to the home screen. (I am not handling its event)

Comment: it is working now. Thanks alot! kindly submit ur answer as a reply so that i can mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Newton It's actually redundant to call ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true), if you're using the parentActivityName attribute.. That being said, when you remove that line from your DisplayMessageActivity, is the "up" affordance still present? –  adneal

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: it works like this but the google tutorial mentions the following "Because the system now knows MainActivity is the parent activity for DisplayMessageActivity, when the user presses the Up button, the system navigates to the parent activity as appropriate—you do not need to handle the Up button's event."

Answer (score 0):

In Your Activity use

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```